# JavaScript type="module" not working in iOS

Tags: javascript, html, ios, module

I am having problems with JavaScript code not executing in iOS devices when I use the `type="module"` attribute.

iOS 14 seems to run it ok, however earlier versions do not.

I created a basic test (see below code) which runs fine on other devices (android mobiles and tablets, desktops) except iOS.

When running the test site on iOS 12 using three different browsers Chrome, Firefox and Safari the script still do not execute. I have even run on multiple iOS 12 devices.

I have discovered when I remove the `type="module` attribute the JavaScript file executes fine.

I thought perhaps iOS was not compatible with modules however according to [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/?search=modules) JavaScript modules are compatible with iOS 11 and greater.

The code for my test site (not working on iOS) is:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test Site</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Test Site v16.0</h1>
    <p id="text-message">:( the module is not working...</p>
    <button id="btn-change">This is a button, can you Click Me</button>
    <script type="module" src="script2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**script2.js**

```
"use strict"

document.getElementById("btn-change").addEventListener("click", (e)=> {
    alert("OK, if you can see this message the script is working....");
} );


const message = document.getElementById("text-message");

message.innerText = "If you can see this it means the module is working! ";
```

I know the problem has something to do with the `type="module"` attribute, however as I import/export in JavaScript (not shown in the test) I need to include this attribute.

I am relatively new to web design so there may be something vital I have not learnt yet, so any assistance or explanation would be much appreciated.

Comment: I can confirm it works in 14.1 Chrome, Safari, Firefox, Brave

Comment: I have tried it in iOS 14 and it seems to work ok.  But iOS 12 is the main culprit here. I do however appreciate your testing. :)